# Change colour of title bar and text to hex values

Tags: android, xml, adt, eclipse-adt

I want to change the colour of the title bar and the text within it to hex values. What is the quickest and easier way to achieve this? Can this be achieved using the manifest xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find how to customize your action bar [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground)

As for setting the values to simply be a hex, the best method to do that is to declare a colors.xml file since any colors you set to the action bar will likely be used elsewhere as well. Declaring it in xml allows for efficient reuse of the same values.

** Edit **
Here's a simple color file.  It would be saved in res/values/colors.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
<color name="default_screen_bg">#20324a</color>
<color name="rounded_container_bg">#80000000</color>
<color name="rounded_container_border">#3b3f44</color>
<color name="light_gray_header_color">#646663</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: If you want to change the action bar style for each activity, you can always change the color programmatically by calling

    `this.getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00FF00")));`

Comment: This would go in any of the activity lifecylce methods up to onResume for your Activity as onResume if the last method called prior to viewing.